# Adding a css class to parsedown elements

Tags: php, css, parsedown

Is it possible to add a css class name to elements marked down using [parsedown](https://parsedown.org)? If so how? Is there any ready extension that does that?

Answer (score 0):

Well, it seems I have found a good one. [Parsedown-extra-plugin](https://github.com/tovic/parsedown-extra-plugin) is a good one to be used. I am keeping this open in case anyone in future finds it useful.

Comment: Hi. Did you find a highlighter for parsedown?

Comment: @JCarlos, Nopes. I haven't searched for that as I didn't require at that time.